# Javascript Draggables callback function issues in 'for' statement

Tags: javascript, callback, draggable

I defined an array :

```
images_array[0]=['c5','user.png','100','100'];
images_array[1]=['c6','user.png','300','400'];
images_array[2]=['c7','mega1.jpg','400','500'];
```

creating draggables like this work:

```
drag_array[images_array[0][0]]=new Draggable(images_array[0][0], { revert: true, onEnd:function(){displaymessage(drag_array[images_array[0][0]]);}});

drag_array[images_array[1][0]]=new Draggable(images_array[1][0], { revert: true, onEnd:function(){displaymessage(drag_array[images_array[1][0]]);}});

drag_array[images_array[2][0]]=new Draggable(images_array[2][0], { revert: true, onEnd:function(){displaymessage(drag_array[images_array[2][0]]);}});
```

Creating draggables in a for statement does not work on the callback function...

```
for (i=0;i<images_array.length;i++) {
drag_array[images_array[i][0]]=new Draggable(images_array[i][0], { revert: true, onEnd:function(){displaymessage(drag_array[images_array[i][0]]);}});
}
```

=> Firefox says that `images_array[i][0]` is not defined...
Removing the callback function

```
drag_array[images_array[i][0]]=new Draggable(images_array[i][0], { revert: true});
```

=> works ... :(

Any idea why the latest argument from the callback function is not working?
tx

Answer (score 1):

This is one typical mistake: Defining functions in a loop. If you define a function that has access to the loop variable `i`, then this variable is **not** evaluated when the function is *defined* but when it is *called*. But at this time, the loop already finished and `i` has some undesired value (in your case `images_array.length + 1`). JavaScript has only [*function scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), not block scope.

You have to *capture* the value of `i` by e.g. using a immediate function:

```
for (i=0;i<images_array.length;i++) {
    drag_array[images_array[i][0]] = new Draggable(
            images_array[i][0], 
            { revert: true, 
              onEnd: (function(index) {
                         return function(){
                             displaymessage(drag_array[images_array[index][0]]);
                         };
                     }(i))
            });
}
```

See also [*Closures for Dummies*](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html), Example 5 and a [lot of questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+closure+loop).

Comment: Thank You! Not so easy when to search when you don't know :)

Comment: @user539872: Your welcome :) You should accept the answer that helped you the most (ok, here is only one answer ;)) by clicking the green tick next to it.